# Qt name of button class

Tags: qt

What is the name of the button class that allows me to select one option from many. This button looks like a normal button but it has arrow on the right side and this arrow allows to pick an option, I.E, button Add would look like this:

`| Add  \/ |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of a ComboBox?

---

[**Wiki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box)

[**QT Docs**](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qcombobox.html)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I've just found that this is a qtoolbutton class. Would you know how to add additional option to be chosen by this button?